# What are the commands to unlock an item in TFS?

Tags: tfs, unlock

What is the command to unlock an item?
My developer made some changes locally (which I don't care) about and went on a vacation, with the items locked in TFS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unlock a file from someone else in Team Foundation Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451637/how-to-unlock-a-file-from-someone-else-in-team-foundation-server)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639515/tfs-how-to-unlock-changes

Answer (score 0):

This is  a question asked by many users and the answer to this and more can be found in the blog post:
http://techkn0w.wordpress.com/2007/06/21/unlocking-items-locked-by-someone-else-in-tfs-source-control